# Vue router scrolling to vue-view comp

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating an application in Vue and I'd like all the main content to be on one page with the option to scroll to specific elements such as LandingPage then below Form, About ..etc.

Is there any way to use a Vue router to set up these components on a page so that when I click on the router-link it scrolls to the element and changes the patch like a normal router-link? The way it should work is that it adds a router-view cluster to the main app.vue component.

After manually scrolling, I would like the patch to be displayed for the currently displayed item (component) and when I press routerlink in the menu, I will be taken to that item.

I have tried several solutions but it doesn't give me results.
Here's an example of a page (funny that it's a vue page) where you can use just such a function.

https://router.vuejs.org/.../advanced/navigation-guards.html

Here is the main link, which in my case would be the / itself, and on the right after selecting an option from the menu it scrolls me to the #something item

Thank you in advance for your help  .

I wanted there to be a component in the app.vue:

```
<router-view name="home" ></router-view>.
<router-view name="Form" ></router-view>.
<router-view name="About" ></router-view>.
```

and displayed the specific components
I tried it like this:

```
const routes = [
  
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'landingPage',
      children: [
          {
            name: '#home',
            path: '/',
            components: {
              landigpage,
            }
          },
          {
            name: '#abaut',
            path: '/',
            component: about,
          }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

Unfortunately, this option does not work
even if these routes will not be nested does not work

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The multiple router-views is an indication of a big misunderstanding of what router-view is for.  I wish I could explain everything but it's _a lot_ so the best thing I can suggest is to read documentation, find tutorials, etc.  [This is a good one](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-use-vue-router-a-complete-tutorial/). Once you have a better understanding, start small, get your router working piece by piece. Don't try to do everything at once. What you want to do eventually is set up your router [scrollbehavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be another alternative for what you're trying to achieve:

You can use "HTML anchor links" where you set the **`id`** attribute of the individual element you want to be scrolled to and using that **`id`** as the value of the href attribute of their respective tab elements (LandingPage, Form, About). When a user clicks on a tab element, e.g `<a href="#about">`, the window will scroll to the element with the corresponding **`id`**. It also hashes the id of the scrolled element to the browser's url bar, e.g https://example.io/#about

Example in code:

```html
<nav>
   <a href="#landingPage">LandingPage</a>
   <a href="#form">Form</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
</nav>

<main>
   <div id="landingPage">
      <!-- LandingPage Contents... -->
   </div>

   <div id="form">
      <!-- Form Contents... -->
   </div>

   <div id="about">
      <!-- About Contents... -->
   </div>
</main>
```

You can throw in some smooth scrolling effect by adding the css:

```css
* {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

For manually changing the url hash indicator when user scrolls to a section, you can watch for the window scroll event, and when scroll position is at position of the indicated tab section, then manually hash the id to the url bar using javascript.